# SSL Self Cert Connection Error

Tags: mamp-pro

When I enable SSL and self sign a cert in MAMP PRO all I get is an "SSL Connection Error" in Chrome and page missing in Safari. If I then change it to http with SSL still enabled on the host the website resolves to the default htdocs directory and not to the host directory. Anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use port 8890 instead of the usual 8888:

https://yourlocaldomain.com:8890